# Firebase Phone Number Auth With No reCAPTCHA

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo, recaptcha

I have a couple questions surrounding Authorization and Firebase and Expo. I am building an app with react native & expo & firebase that requires a login. I set it up to handle the phone verification with a text message to verify and reCAPTCHA to confirm that they are not a "robot".

With that said, I have talked to a number of people who say that reCAPTCHA is not necessary and I have noted that majority of apps that use phone as OAuth don't use reCAPTCHA. So my questions are:

1. Can I use Firebase Auth without reCAPTCHA without having to eject my app from EXPO?
2. Is there another way to implement the phone verification without Firebase?
3. I am using google sign-in as another option, does anyone have strong feelings about oAuth options? I prefer to stay away from social platforms for a number of reasons. But I am curious if anyone has an preference/ opinion on the matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is no real need for recaptcha with mobile apps. Auth with social or email verification works just fine. I removed the recaptch from the app.